# Passing Lambda as Parameter into Repository Method in EFCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement the repository pattern as described [here](http://appetere.com/post/passing-include-statements-into-a-repository)

However, the relationships are not being included.

```
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetWithRelationship(params Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
  var set = _context.MyEntities;
  foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
  {
    set.Include(includeProperty);
  }
  return set.ToList();
}
```

The following works however:

```
return _context.MyEntities.Include(x => x.RelatedEntity).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-assign `set` to the returned value of the `Include()` method. But, in order to avoid compilation errors, you'll have to treat your `set` as `IQueryable<MyEntity>` first:

```
var set = _context.MyEntities as IQueryable<MyEntity>;

foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
{
    set = set.Include(includeProperty);
}

return set.ToList();
```

Comment: that throws: Cannot implicitly convert type 'IIncludableQueryable<MyEntity, object>' to 'DbSet<MyEntity>'. I can convert the types in the context to IQueryable, but then I lose methods like '.Add()'